# Is there a linguistic term for 'defensive' phrases, such as "with all due respect" and "no offense"?

Tags: terminology

Apologies if this is not a linguistics question.

I often notice how phrases such as "*with all due respect, [...]*" and "*no offense, but [...]*" are used defensively or to 'soften' a negative or critical comment. Is this a known quantity in (socio?)linguistics, and is there any research I could look into?

Comment: In common parlance those might be *weasel words*, in less-common parlance they might be examples of *tergiversation*.  In linguistical terms, I haven't a clue!

Comment: you may want to take a look at https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=45494